# How to handle TIdHTTP fatal network errors without interrupting thread's execution?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception, indy

I'd like to elaborate on how to properly handle fatal network exceptions raised by `TIdHTTP` inside TThread's `Execute` procedure.

My app runs a `while..do` loop inside the `Execute` procedure. Each loop makes a `TIdHTTP.Get()` call. The exceptions are handled at the loop level. There is also an upper level handler of `on E: Exception do` (level of `Execute`).

The scenario assumes a *fatal network error* during active network operations (i.e. adapter outage, "connection reset by peer", etc.).

10 threads are serialized to make `TIdHTTP.Get()` requests from inside the loop. The app is running on a laptop when a home router unexpectedly hangs. Here comes #10054. Suppose that the network returns within 10 minutes. I want to make sure that in case of a sudden network death, each thread somehow:

1. Detects that *(well, that's the easiest)*.
2. Waits until the network comes back.
3. Makes sure the network is up.
4. Re-establishes connection and restores all network hood.
5. Continues the loop.

The desired result is to keep the thread up and running and just survive the temporary network problem. The threads must periodically check if the network is back. When it is, the exception handler must restore all network hood calling thread's `RestoreNetworkConnection` and then continue the loop.

What I definitely don't want - is to stop threads' execution.

#### Questions

1. Which events/exceptions shall I intercept to handle fatal network errors?
2. Where to place exception handlers within `Execute`?
3. What is correct way of re-establishing connection back to normal state?

Comment: You're actually asking 6 questions in this post, since `TIdHTTP` and `TADOConnection` need different ways for error handling and restoring. That's quite much for one post...

Comment: @TLama Oh, that's true... Thanks for mentioning that. Would you suggest to make two separate posts one for TIdHTTP and one for TADOConnection?

Comment: Yes, please. But anyway, I don't think you are really looking for handling only network failures. There's a lot of other bad things that may happen while those components are working. Think about all those 4xx HTTP errors returned by the server, or all the exceptions returned when something bad happens on the DBMS... Losing connection can be detected for both components, but that's just a small part of what can fail.

Comment: @TLama (I did, thanks!) Actually everything works just great. App survives `EIdSocketError`, `EIdReadTimeout`, etc. Now proper handling of #10054 and other 'hardware errors' will make me absolutely happy :)

Comment: @TLama.
"This is exactly the same question as your linked question, with the only difference being the class of Exception you would catch and minor differences in the re-establishing of the connection. It could surely be combined into a single question about handling the general network exceptions in a thread, and then a second, separate question (linked back to the first) could ask only about the differences, rather than posting two separate long questions containing 90% same content. (It's really not appropriate here to copy/paste long questions, change a couple of phrases, and post again)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do something like this:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  NetworkDown: Boolean;
begin
  NetworkDown := False;
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      // wait for a successful HTTP response...
      repeat
        if Terminated then Exit;
        try
          IdHTTP.Get(...);
          Break;
        except
          on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
            // process HTTP error as needed...
          end;
          on E: EIdSocketError do begin
            NetworkDown := True;
            // process socket error as needed...
          end;
          on E: Exception do begin
            // process any other error as needed...
            raise;
          end;
        end;
        Sleep(1000);
      until False;

      // got a response, check if network was previously down
      if NetworkDown then
      begin
        NetworkDown := False;
        RestoreNetworkConnection;
      end;

      // now process HTTP response as needed ...
    end;
  except
    on Exception do begin
      // process fatal error as needed ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```