# How to handle ADO fatal network errors without interrupting threads' execution?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception, ado

NOTE: A question similar to [How to handle TIdHTTP fatal network errors without interrupting thread's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302080/how-to-handle-tidhttp-fatal-network-errors-without-interrupting-threads-executi) but handling TADOConnection fatal network errors.

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions on handling fatal network errors raised by `TADOConnection` inside TThread's `Execute` procedure.

My app runs a `while..do` loop inside the `Execute` procedure. Each loop makes a database update via `TADOConnection.Execute()`. All loop exceptions are handled at the loop level. There is also an upper level handler of `on E: Exception do` (level of `Execute`).

During active network operations a *fatal network error* occurs on the remote database server. Something went wrong and in the middle of the loop threads report they cannot find path a database server (Named Pipes Provider error, EOleException, etc.) The network gets back within 10 minutes.

I want to make sure that in case of a sudden network death, each thread somehow:

1. Detects that *(well, that's the easiest)*.
2. Smokes a joint and waits until the network comes back.
3. Makes sure the network is up.
4. Re-establishes connection and restores all network hood.
5. Continues the loop.

The desired result is to keep the thread up and running and just survive the temporary network problem. The threads must periodically check if the network is back. When it is, the exception handler must restore all ADO hood calling thread's `RestoreNetworkConnection` and then continue the loop.

What I definitely don't want - is to stop threads' execution.

#### Questions

1. Which events/exceptions shall I intercept to handle fatal network errors?
2. Where to place exception handlers within `Execute`?
3. What is correct way of re-establishing connection back to normal state?

Comment: How to detect? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2289260/2087187

Comment: This is exactly the same question as your linked question, with the only difference being the class of Exception you would catch and minor differences in the re-establishing of the connection. It could surely be combined into a single question about handling the general network exceptions in a thread, and then a second, separate question (linked back to the first) could ask only about the differences, rather than posting two separate long questions containing 90% same content. (It's really not appropriate here to copy/paste long questions, change a couple of phrases, and post again as new.)

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that the question is long, and contains 90% of the  initial question, but: 1) In my initial post there were 2 questions together and then I was suggested to split them; 2) I think that they are relatively different in terms of handling exceptions and restoring functionality.
In general I feel somewhat confused because different users suggest totally opposite actions. But my point was to attract different audiences. I.e. the TIdHTTP question will most likely be responded by Remy Lebeau, who may not want to deal with ADO stuff.

Comment: @Ken, that was me who adviced OP to ask two questions for each component separately because of that "only difference". That difference is quite big when we are talking about proper exception handling. Also, resuming (and cancelling) connections is different.

Comment: Then Remy can deal with the second question when you post it. Your question is the equivalent of a long post asking about how to add two integer variables (A & B), and then another long post asking how to add two integer variables (A & C), where the only difference is that C is derived from a function result instead of a simple assignment. You're not getting two different suggestions; you're getting the same one twice but you implemented the first one incorrectly. Ask *one question* about exception handling without thread termination with a specific issue, and a second about differences later.

Comment: @TLama: I saw it. There's no point in restating 90% of the same information to explain a question about the 10% difference, and the same applies if it's 75/25%. The majority of the question is the same, and after the first is answered, the second can refer to the first and ask about the specific differences, IMO.

Comment: Gentlemen, as I am still new here I will do whatever you both agree on. Honestly I am more with TLama in this particular discussion, but for the sake of harmony I am ready to re-join the questions.
Again: please let me know how to process.

Comment: @KenWhite- I agree: Looks to me like two (or three) questions but not set up correctly: One question is about how to keep a thread alive until an interrupting condition is fixed-Remy answered that in the first question and the answer is applicable here too-it's the same question. The second (and third) question is how to catch the various exceptions, and how to ensure conditions are restored to a healthy state when possible-that's really two questions, one about ADO and one about HTTP connections. Remy did not address that aspect at all, AFAIK.